# watchOS App doesn't get installed on watch / magically appearing files in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I have a very strange bug with my application and xcode behaviour.
I was working on my ios/watchos app when suddenly my app would launch on the iphone but would not get installed on the watch (both hardware, not simulator). I looked in the console to find following error:

```
0x16bfe3000 -[ACXServerInstallOperation receivedDictionaryOrData:]: 591: Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error ApplicationVerificationFailed ; Extended 0xe8008017 ; Desc Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.B4ZRD0/extracted/Payload/Kontostand WatchKit App.app : 0xe8008017 (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.))
```

Unfortunately google was of no help, so i went to figure out what was the problem. I use source control to follow my work (not the built in from xcode, but "sourcetree"). When i looked there some five files were edited, that i didn't touch. Also there were 4 new files out of nowhere, that i haven't had a clue were they came from:

[image: mystical appearing files]

From the nature of the files it seems, that xcode added them automatically to ensure compatibility to the new watch series 4, but no action from my side was taken, to add these files.
Further more when i try to delete these files / revert the changes through git - then these files will almost instantanously reappear.

For me it seems that these files cause the issue with my app not being installed, since i reverted to a commit where my app was running smoothly. The 'magic' files appeared nonetheless and my app would not install...

Has anybody an idea what could help?

**Edit 1:** I started a clean new project just to see if this would be fine: This installs as aspected. No errors while installing.

Comment: The `Contents.json` files keep track of what image you drag to each of the slots in the asset catalog along with any slicing, etc that you setup in the catalog. If you add new images to your asset catalog you will see new content files to go with them. Likewise changing an image will cause the contents file to get updated.

Comment: The thing is: i didn't touch any asset catalog, image or whatever. I worked on plain old code the whole time... I didn't even went near the complications for that matter. I was concentrated on watchConnectivity the whole time.

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode?  For odd install behavior, this is important to try.

Comment: actually a restart alone didn't did the trick. i had to clean the project and build all targets (2 frameworks, the watchkit extension and ios app) from scratch and then run it on the device. this works. Unfortunately i have to do this now almost all the time. in fact i do it every time, since there is possible data loss if i risk to encounter the forementioned problem. This does cause an increase in build time of course. :-/